# change cell range reference based on other cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet where I load a set of data in. Each column is a category, but I do not know the specific name/headline/title of each column in advance. I can manually translate the column name to a given category and write that in another sheet. Also, I do not know the number of columns and rows in the data set. See the images for an example where I have a data set and a table where I manually type which column is which category.

The data set:

[image: data set]

A table where I manually set which column is which category:

[image: a table where I manually set which column is which category]

Lets say I now want to use the data associated with a specific category (a column) in a formula such that I take the sum of the column with this category (e.g. "Force" in the example which I have manually stated in the other sheet in cell B2 is column B).

The final result should be that I take the sum of column B (where the column letter is read in the other sheet in cell B2) from row 2 to the end of the column. I believe the two things I do not know to make this work is:

1. How do I use the value in a cell to refer to a column in another sheet?
2. How do I take the sum of a column from a known start row to the end (unknown number of rows in the data)?

Any help is much appreciated! :-)

Comment: You can use INDIRECT perhaps. As far as question 2, just sum the entire column.

Comment: `=SUM(INDIRECT("'Sheet2'!" & B2 & ":" & B2))`

Comment: or better yet, instead of column letter use the column number `A=1`,`B=2`,... and use the non volatile INDEX:  `=SUM(INDEX(Sheet2!A:I,0,B2))`

Comment: Thank you Scott Craner! This was exactly what I was looking for. Can you turn it into an answer? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use INDIRECT:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'Sheet2'!" & B2 & ":" & B2))
```

But I would recommend, instead of column letter use the column number `A=1`,`B=2`,... and use the non volatile INDEX:

```
=SUM(INDEX(Sheet2!A:I,0,B2))
```